# Blender Python: Access Selected Collections?

Tags: python, collections, development

How would I go about accessing the list of selected collections? It seems as though the selection state of collections is something specific to the Outliner? But I can't seem to find anything in the API docs about a selection list that would contain collections.

Comment: I downloaded the full Blender source code to attempt to figure this out. Unfortunately, it didn't help much. Inside the C function that handles collection_delete (collection_delete_exec), they seem to use "outliner_tree_traverse( soops, &soops->tree, 0, TSE_SELECTED, collection_find_data_to_edit, &data);" to access the list of selected collections. I believe the TSE_SELECTED flag may be related, but I cannot find any code exposing this to python.

Comment: I'm still very interested in learning how to do this in case someone wanders by that might know how. At this point, I can't even find a hack to accomplish this. What I'm looking for is either (A) a way to access a list of selected outliner objects, or (B) a way to detect weather or not a specific collection is selected